# Jenkins job (include branches)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9XoA.png)I have TFS server and JOB on Jenkins, which works always when developer make changes.
I need to configure job, which will start ONLY if developer make changes in special branch. If developer makes changes in another directory - Jenkins won't do anything.

Comment: Directory or Branch? Be specific.

Comment: Also, how the job is being triggered? Is it via Jenkins webhooks or polling or manually?

Comment: It works with TFS plugin which configured between TFS and Jenkins. When someone made changes in TFS - plugin push Jenkins

Comment: Okay, I get it now. So, basically, you are using TFS webhook. Which automatically tells Jenkins when to build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a change in the specific branch then you can configure your job as follows: (Observer the branch specifier. Instead of */master, replace the branch name you want to build)

[image],

Comment: i explained not correct. in my branch, i have main folder "SRC". there are many sub folders which our dev.team uses. The main idea is - to configure JOB only for Caching. I mean that if someone change another sub folder TFS don't push Jenkins to start make a build.
At this moment if someone change something in another folders - TFS push Jenkins to make a build.

Comment: It's bit unclear with your explanation. Could you please provide a sample branch hierarchy (Like the folder structure you are talking about)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9XoA.png
There is a structure. i need to configure JOB only if someone make changes in "caching" directory.,

Comment: now it works like that - if someone change make changes in some of folder - JOB starts to work. i need to exclude other folders.